# Java Set in memory with search

Tags: java, search, set

I need to cache a large amount of data in memory and be able to search it very efficiently. It is essentially a list of strings and, for a given input, I want to return a list of the strings that contain that input.

For example, if the list contains the following strings:

```
abc def
def ghi
ghi jkl
```

And the input is:

```
ef
```

I want to return the first two strings as output (preferably in alphabetical order).

I was thinking of using a Java [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementation, put all the strings in it and put it in memory. For any given input, I would loop through the `Set` and find the records that contain the input using `String.contains()` and add the results to another `Set` or `List`.

Would that be the most efficient way of accomplishing this? Performance is very important and the amount of data is very large (10s of megabytes). I can have a dedicated server instance with lots of memory just for this purpose if necessary.

Comment: Have a look at [Guava Caches](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained).

Comment: *"10s of megabyes"*, how many megabytes? Like 100mb or 1000mb? Have you thought about just using an external database like PostgreSQL which supports full text serches? What about an internal DB like Derby? You mention performance is a concern, have you tried a DB solution and found that the performance is not suitable and need a faster way? Also checkout this PDF regaring fulltext searches is PostgreSQL, https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/2/25/Full-text_search_in_PostgreSQL_in_milliseconds-extended-version.pdf Looks pretty fast.

Comment: @ug_ I would say around 50 or 60 megs. Are you saying that your suggested database solutions would be FASTER than my idea of caching the data in memory? I want to have the best performance possible.

Comment: @MickMnemonic That looks very interesting and I hadn't considered it. Do you think it is FASTER than my proposed solution? Wouldn't it require a primary data source and then it would cache the data lazily? This would likely cause the initial operations to be slower, right?

Comment: @stepanian I'm not sure if it would be using a database would be faster. However databases are build for doing this kind of stuff fast, combined with being built in generally C they do well and have good support. If you don't want to use a database then looking at how they implement their indexes would be a exceptional way of getting a solution.

Comment: @stepanian, now that I read your description again, it seems that you want to do partial searches by the input, which would probably make Guava Caches impractical as they're based on `HashMap`s.

Comment: Also have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543919/simple-in-memory-full-text-search-solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set` or `HashSet` in particular won't give a great performance, because you have to iterate over the entire `set` and do `contains` to check if the input is a substring. You definitely need a string data-structure.

- Have a look at [Suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) and [Generalized suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) in particular, it gives you O(m) time to check if **S** of length **m** is a subsstring or exists in the tree.
- You could build an [inverted index](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/a-first-take-at-building-an-inverted-index-1.html)

And finally, you can just use [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) which is a text inverted index for Java and works off-heap as well

Comment: Is there a Java implementation of a data structure that is appropriate for this? I don't mind using Lucene, but I would be using a very small subset of its functionality. If there was a way I can use just a data structure that is resident in memory, I think that would be preferable. Any further insights?

Comment: @stepanian have a look at this implementation https://github.com/abahgat/suffixtree

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I will either use Lucene or the Java suffix tree implementation. I will evaluate both.