# How to write postgresql query in hsql

Tags: java, postgresql, hsqldb

I have a java app and postgre sql DB. postgre sql has plainto_tsquery() and ts_rank() methods. And in postgre sql the command :

```
SELECT  lastname, firstname,middlename, comments, state, organization FROM persons m, plainto_tsquery('key string') q
WHERE q @@ m.tsvector_person
ORDER BY  ts_rank(tsvector_person, q)  DESC ;
```

works fine.

How can I write this command in hsql?
I didn't find anything to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch.html) functionality of PostgreSQL. This is [not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543919) for HSQLDB. If you need a 100% Java DB with this functionality, take a look at [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#feature_list).

Comment: I can use only PostgreSQL and I need Full Text Search and Sort results. I wrote a FUNCTION that return like `setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(target.lastname, '')), 'AA')`. But I don't know how to write a method which can sort results and returns List

Comment: Your question is stated as "How can I write this command in hsql?". That is different from what you are saying here. So please describe your question *as clear as possible*.